# node js. install npm packages from hard disk

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

How can I install `npm` package to Node.JS project from hdd. I think admin at work blocked `npm`.

I installed `npm` and when I try to write in cmd `npm install express` for example I got connection timeout.

But I have find back door, I can clone npm package via git desktop from github to hdd.

Somebody can help me ?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-locally

Comment: john when i run NPM INSTALL than npm do connecting to https://registry.npmjs.org/ automatically. i check today all options

Comment: Copy the dependencies from a similar computer (don't mix windows/macos if you have e.g. node-gyp in the dependency tree). Your IT team might also have its own mirror within the company (for antivirus checks, etc.) which you can define as your main registry with npm config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to regularly install and update packages if your IT team blocked all access to all registries — you would need to essentially make a backup of thousands of packages to your computer for that to work. What you could try is using a different registry, for example `npm --registry [registry url] install express`. [This is a list of some registry mirrors](https://github.com/amio/npm-mirrors/blob/master/index.js). If your workplace uses JS though, I would talk with the IT team to make sure they can unblock the main registry.

Comment: i try to install from yarn but also blocked.

Comment: I would definitely talk to the IT team then. There's not much you can do if they're blocking all sorts of registries. They could have a firewall in place that thinks that's some sort of malicious traffic, in which case they should be able to whitelist some domains.

Comment: no way to find backdoor for installing dependencies ?

Comment: You could make a full mirror of the registry while on a different network and keep that on your computer or an external drive. Or you could try using a VPN, but npm is blocked, VPN connections are probably also blocked.

Comment: I checked now at home something. I have cloned from github for example express, than I'm disabled wifi and did this "npm /Users/anthonyfink//work/test/express install express"  but this i did in macosx. Windows i don't know if gonna work. in package.json its looks like   "dependencies": {
    "express": "file:../../work/test/express",
    "install": "^0.13.0"
  }